# How to display factorized values as a string (text) on a plot?

Tags: r, plot

I have a survey dataset (see image below) where each column contains  values that represent either a likert scale value (1=Never, 2=Sometimes...) or a Degree (1=Highschool, 2= College...).

```
education  country HP_pre_junk_food_1
5  142  4
6  142  5
6  24  4
6  24  3
8  65  3
3  143  4
6  35  4
...
```

I made a boxplot for `education` (see image below). And I want to display actual text instead of the numeric values. I want to display "Master Degree" instead of the value "8".

[image: my boxplot]

Comment: see `?axis` or `?scale_y_continuous` if you use ggplot

Comment: Question should be asking about axis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `yaxt="n"` to suppress the y axis labels and then use `axis` to print whatever you would like.  (You may need to change the margins to get some extra space.)

```
###Create some test data
set.seed(2017)
Education = c(sample(1:8, 15, replace=TRUE), 
        sample(2:7, 8, replace=TRUE),
        sample(3:6, 6, replace=TRUE),
        sample(4:5, 4, replace=TRUE))
EdLevels = c("None", "Elementary", "HighSchool", "JuniorCollege", 
    "College", "Masters", "PhD", "Other") 

par(mar=c(5.1,7,4.1,2.1))
boxplot(Education, yaxt="n")
axis(2, at=1:8, labels=EdLevels, las=1)
```

[image: Boxplot with Text labels]